# Why Spring Framework does not throw DuplicateKeyException when MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException occurs?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

`DuplicateKeyException` extends `DataIntegrityViolationException`. However `DataIntegrityViolation` Exception is thrown by Spring framework if any unique key constraint is broken instead of `DuplicateKeyException`.

I have an order table in which order code is unique. When I try to insert an order with an duplicate code, I'm expecting a DuplicateKeyException, however I am getting DataIntegrityViolationException.

Here is the stack trace:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Duplicate entry '1-561336327' for key 'code_UNIQUE'; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1-561336327' for key 'code_UNIQUE' 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1-561336327' for key 'code_UNIQUE' –
```

Anybody knows if this is expected?

Comment: Were you able to produce this issue. Without stacktrace and sample code, nothing much can be said.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

From the Spring doc (seems fairly clear to me)

public class DuplicateKeyException
extends DataIntegrityViolationException

Exception thrown when an attempt to insert or update data results in violation of an primary key or unique constraint. Note that this is not necessarily a purely relational concept; unique primary keys are required by most database types. 
[http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DuplicateKeyException.html]

public class DataIntegrityViolationException
extends NonTransientDataAccessException

Exception thrown when an attempt to insert or update data results in violation of an integrity constraint. Note that this is not purely a relational concept; unique primary keys are required by most database types. 
[http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataIntegrityViolationException.html]

Comment: Can you point out a scenario where DuplicateKeyException will be thrown?

Comment: Well: "violation of an primary key or unique constraint"!  Do you have an actual scenario or are you just trying to determine some difference?

Comment: This might help you:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58227/ch7.htm#1759

Comment: I have an order table in which order code is unique. When I try to insert an order with an duplicate code, I'm expecting a DuplicateKeyException, however I am getting DataIntegrityViolationException. Isn't this violating unique constraint?

Comment: And there's no chance some interface is returning the more general type and you do in fact get the DuplicateKeyException you just don't know it?

Comment: I don't think that is the case. Here is the stack trace I'm getting:    org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Duplicate entry '1-561336327' for key 'code_UNIQUE'; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null];                                                       nested exception is  org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1-561336327' for key 'code_UNIQUE'
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1-561336327' for key 'code_UNIQUE'

Comment: Ah ok, in Hibernate Spring maps ConstraintViolationException to a DataIntegrityViolationException.
If it helps it maps Hibernate's NonUniqueObjectException to DuplicateKeyException.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/NonUniqueObjectException.html

Comment: See: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils for other spring-hibernate mappings